# Redis in a threaded environment is inconsistent

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, redis

I'm having some problems with redis when running in a threaded environment.

I have a class called AwaitableParallelForeachWorker in which i can run a specific function for each item in a payload. (I know it's not pretty, but it does the job)

```
 public class AwaitableParallelForeachWorker : IAwaitableParallelForeachWorker
 {
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
    private int _tasksCompleted;

    public async Task Run<T>(Func<T, Task> action, IEnumerable<T> payload)
    {
        var list = payload.ToList();
        var tasks = list.Select(x => new Task(async () =>
        {
            await action(x);
            TaskDone();
        }));
        Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task => task.Start());
        while (_tasksCompleted < list.Count)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }

    public void TaskDone()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            _tasksCompleted++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the redis cache code:

```
 public class NewsappRedisCache : INewsappRedisCache
 {
    private static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisCache"];

    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> LazyConnection =
        new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConnectionString));

    private static IDatabase MimerArticleDatabase => Connection.GetDatabase(2);

    public async Task<MimerArticle> GetMimerArticleAsync(Guid id)
    {
        var redisValue = await MimerArticleDatabase.StringGetAsync($"{nameof(MimerArticle)}-{id}");
        if (!redisValue.HasValue) return null;
        var mimerArticle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MimerArticle>(redisValue.ToString());
        return mimerArticle;
    }
```

I have written this simple test which calls my redis cache 1000 times using the AwaitableParallelForeachWorker

```
  public class Test
  {
    private NewsappRedisCache _redisCache;

    [Fact]
    public async void TestRedis()
    {
        var guids = new List<Guid>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            guids.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        _redisCache = new NewsappRedisCache();
        await new AwaitableParallelForeachWorker().Run(CallRedis, guids);
    }

    private async Task CallRedis(Guid id)
    {
        await _redisCache.GetMimerArticleAsync(id);
    }
}
```

Now it gets weird. Sometimes the 1000 gets to the redis cache is executed in a split second. I have verified that the gets actually hit the cache by checking the azure portal. But sometimes each get takes about 1 second.

I have no idea why. I've tried changing the functionality of AwaitableParallelForeachWorker, but it keeps being inconsistent. 
If i run each get in a normal foreach it executes just fine, but not as fast as when the AwaitableParallelForeachWorker actually works.

So i'm stuck thinking it has something to do with threading/tasks.

Anyone who can offer some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the exact reason, but I can't fit this in a comment either, so here are some things to consider:

- shouldn't the test method be `async Task`, not `async void`?  Some test frameworks handle this arguably-incorrect usage, but perhaps yours doesn't.  If the framework has no way of knowing when the method is complete, it'll think everything is done at the first await.
- Your `Run()` method could be significantly simplified as:

  ```
  public Task Run<T>(Func<T, Task> action, IEnumerable<T> payload)
  {
      return Task.WhenAll(payload.Select(action));
  }
  ```

  and get rid of the rest of the class.
- Your `CallRedis()` method doesn't need the state-machine overhead; instead:

  ```
  private Task CallRedis(Guid id)
  {
      return _redisCache.GetMimerArticleAsync(id);
  }
  ```
- While I'm saving you lines:

  ```
  var guids = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
  // :)
  ```

Comment: The change to Task.WhenAll(payload.Select(action)) did the trick!
I had previously used: return Task.WhenAll(payload.Select(async x => await action(x))), but that did the same as the weird Run method i made. That's why i ended up implementing Run in that way... I clearly don't get async and await just yet.
Anwyays thanks a lot!